# Who's Online Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains a Session ID, user ID, and Last Activity field.
Each time a user accesses the website, their session ID is inserted into the database.

If a Session ID is present, but User ID is set to 0, then the user is marked as a guest.

If a Session ID is present, and the User ID field is not 0, then the user is marked as a registered online users

**My Question:**

What's the best way to display the total users online, and split this information up in to how many are guests, and how many are registered? Can this be done with one query?

**Example:** There are currently **xxx** users online. **xxx** are registered, and **xxx** are guests.

Many Thanks,

FishSword

---

**EDIT:**

My session MySQL table contains the following fields:

- sid - Stores the session ID.
- user - Stores the user id of a logged in user. 0 is stored if the user is a guest.
- ip - Stores the ip address of the user.
- updated - stores a timestamp of when the user was last active.

**Example Data:**

See example data below. sud, user, ip, updated

- sd456asdfas65asf465, 0, 192.168.128.33, 1315181434
- v654xc654v65xc4v65z, 24, 192.168.128.65, 1315181529
- dfsddas654g4sa6g4s6, 0, 192.168.128.33, 1315203155
- y4g4df65gv4ff6sd54g, 69, 192.168.128.76, 1315181134
- c4cs546sd654sdf654df, 42, 192.168.128.85, 1315181101
- if465fsdf465sd46z65, 24, 192.168.128.65, 1315203144
- dasd645as46d5a46465, 69, 192.168.128.12, 1315181134

  1. Example 1 and 3 should only be logged once (as one guest online), as they have the same user id, and have came from the same computer/ip address.
  2. Example 2 and 6 should only be logged once (as one member online), as they have the same user id, and have came from the same computer/ip address.
  3. Even though example 4 and 7 have came from a different computer, user 69 should only be logged as once (one member online), as they have the same user id, and have came from the same computer/ip address.

Cheers! ;)

Comment: @rabudde: I think he don't know how, in case of 0%

Comment: It's not even a poor quality question, so it's not like you don't know how to use SO... accept your best answers in your other questions, and you will get more contributions.

Answer (score 2):

Make table

```
ID | SessID    | Guest
1  | someRand  | 1
2  | someRand2 | 0
```

And select it like

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sessions WHERE Guest = 1) as guests, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sessions WHERE Guest = 0) as users
```

and show it  like

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sessions WHERE Guest = 1) as guests, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sessions WHERE Guest = 0) as users");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
echo "There are ".($row['users'] + $row['guests'])." users online, ".$row['users']." registered and ".$row['guests']." are guests";
```

Comment: I have not downvoted, but I think you can do it without creating extra table and without doing two `SELECT`s (see my post)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS online,IFNULL(SUM(user_id=0),0) AS guests,IFNULL(SUM(user_id>0),0) AS registered FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ip_address,user_id FROM sessions
) x
```

Comment: If there are no users online, the total guests/registered users doesn't output as zero. How do I state that there are 0 guests/registered users online?

Comment: Have a look at MySQLs `IFNULL` function and see me edited post

Comment: How do I amended this query so that it only counts an ip address with more than one instance of a certain userNumber as one (e.g 0, 254) user?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it hasn't worked. It still displays 2 members/guests/users online, even though there are two users with the same userNumber under the same IP Address? (e.g. 0, 12) - What does the "x" do at the end of the query? It appears to be required.

Comment: It would be fine if you can post an exact table structure of your session table and some example data in your original post.

Comment: Got it working - Why do you need the x at the end? Can this be done without the x?

Comment: every subquery results in a dedicated table internally. this "derived" table has to have an alias to be handled by MySQL properly. in my case this alias is `x`

Comment: Just out of interest, can this be done a different way, so that an alias isn't needed?

Answer (score 1):

Create a table (recommended) or in user table where to store a last action timestamp column.

```
user_id | action_timestamp    |
------------------------------
      1 | 2011-08-15 13:02:00 |
      2 | 2011-08-15 12:34:00 |
      3 | 2011-08-15 11:05:00 |
```

Then to pull last online users for interval you make following select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS t WHERE TIMEDIFF(NOW(), action_timestamp) < '00:15:00' /* fifteen minutes */
```

Now you have a count of online users in the last 15 minutes.

This will decrease overall performance (depending on the request and records), because every time the user makes a request you have to set two queries, one to insert/update record, and one for displaying the stats bellow.

You may combine the two queries into one multi-query to compensate a little bit.

Comment: I am currently storing the date/time in the db using time(). How would you check the difference using this?

Comment: Set the field TIMESTAMP db type. And update the record for the given user on each request he have made.
`UPDATE table SET action_timestamp = NOW() WHERE user_id = <current_user_id_from_session_for_example>`.

TIMEDIFF is returning difference between now (current datetime) and the store one in the user field as time, then we check if it is less than 15 minutes. By this way we know who is online in last 15 minutes.

You can change the '00:15:00' with custom value.

Actually, php does not allow you to track precisely who is online, whereas asp.net for example allows you.